# Can I restrict capitalizedString not to capitalising superscript text in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

When I apply capitalizedString to a string I don't want superscript to be capitialised. Is there any solution of it or I need to do it manually ?

```
NSStirng *title = @"25th event annual";
title = [title capitalizedString] ;

// Current output 
25Th Event Annual

// Needed output
25th Event Annual
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some hack for this like

```
NSStirng *title = @"25th event annual";
title = [title capitalizedString]; // 25TH Event Annual
NSString *finaltitle = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Th"
                                     withString:@"th"]; // 25th Event Annual
```

But this will work fine when you don't have Th in your original string. Or else use subscript function and make parts of string as capitalised and concat it again. Answer of ivarun will work in that case.

Comment: This may work but i think it will replace all Th with th which i don't want. But nice try thanks @Pushkraj

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution.

```
NSString *title = @"25th event annual";
NSRange rng = [title rangeOfString:@" "];
NSString *first = [title substringToIndex:rng.location];
NSString *last = [title substringFromIndex:rng.location + 1];
NSString  *lastPart = [last capitalizedString];
NSString *fullString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",first,lastPart];
```

Output you want :D

25th Event Annual

Hope it works for you. :)

Comment: Your solution is specific to a string!! I can have any string like @"my 20th brthdy blah blah".  It is not necessary that the string with number is always at the first. By the way Thanks ivarun

Comment: @Bhumika yes it is. I think you should mention this in question too. isn't it ? :P

Comment: The question should automatically come into your mind as a developer right ? :p

Comment: @Bhumika i'm not that much intelligent :D like you :P